# how to rewrite wordpress custom pagination in functions.php

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function, pagination

I have a custom pagination in my theme that uses `paginate_links` and has:

```
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
```

Right now it outputs links URL like this:

```
domain.com/cat-variable-name/?cpage=2
```

and I like the to overwrite them like this:

```
domain.com/cat-variable-name/cpage/2/
```

I already tried this without sucess:

```
add_rewrite_rule('cpage/([^/]+)/pagina/([0-9]+)?$',
   'index.php?cpage=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
   'top');
```

**Note:** Please keep in mind that "**cat-variable-name**" and "**page_number**" never are the same.

Comment: Check the `format` parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: @CBroe format is blank (`'format' => '',`) but no mather the mask I use there, it never outputs the way I need. That's why I need to rewrite this on functions.php

Comment: Adding a rewrite rule won’t help you, because those work in the other “direction” – they determine what the _incoming requests_ are rewritten to. They have nothing whatsoever to do with what link `href` attributes you output.

Comment: @CBroe [this is the code i'm using](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56848/wp-list-categories-pagination#57404). What you suggest me to do to solve this?